# How do I mock a Where clause in EF4

Tags: entity-framework, rhino-mocks, entity-framework-4

I am re-writing this question to make it clearer what I need to do. I am trying to use Rhino-Mock to test:

```
    public IQueryable<TxRxMode> GetAllModes()
    {
        return m_context.TxRxModes.Where(txRxMode => txRxMode.Active);
    }
```

Here's the code:

```
var context = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IProjectContext>();

//Returns an empty list
context.Expect(c => c.TxRxModes.Where(Arg<Func<TxRxMode, bool>>.Is.Anything)).Return(new List<TxRxMode>().AsQueryable());
```

`TxRxModes` in an `IObjectSet` property on the context and I want it to return an empty `IQueryable<TxRxMode`> object when the `return m_context.TxRxModes.Where(txRxMode => txRxMode.Active);` code is called.

When I run this, the Expect method call throws the an ArgumentNullException:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: predicate

I have tried the simpler:

```
IObjectSet<TxRxMode> modes = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IObjectSet<TxRxMode>>();
context.Expect(c => c.TxRxModes).Return(modes);
```

but this throws a null reference exception when I call

```
return m_context.TxRxModes.Where(txRxMode => txRxMode.Active);
```

Basically, this is part of the method I am trying to mock, so the key question is how do I mock this Where statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is actually a global static method and you shouldn't be mocking it. It operates on an IEnumerable however and you could just mock that.

Its kind of a hassle doing it with rhino mocks however.  I would recommend doing the mock manually (if you need to do it at all).

Comment: Good point about the static, I'd missed that. I have tried to manually mock the IObjectSet interface and now need to provide an IQueryProvider object. More digging needed!